# MVC 3 child actions not cached with OutputCache attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

My child actions aren't being cached. I don't know why.

My master page calls a child action:

```
@Html.Action("Header", "Layout", new { selectedMarket = Model.SelectedMarket })

    [ChildActionOnly]
    [OutputCache(Duration=60)]
    public PartialViewResult Header(Guid selectedMarket)
    {
        var model = _marketService.GetHeaderViewModel(selectedMarket);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

This child action is executed and the partial is re-rendered on each and every request.

Note: I can successfully cache the entire page with OutputCache. It's just the donut hole caching that isn't working for me.

Comment: How are you rendering the child action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the OutputCacheAttribute in the following manner:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3660, VaryByParam="selectedMarket")]
```

This will create a separate cache for each selectedMarket (I suppose that is what you need). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Eventually, yes. I was trying to get the simple case working first, then add that complexity. I added the VaryByParam as you suggested, but my child action and view are still executed for each request.

Comment: Apparently, it automatically varies on the route values. In my test, the selectedMarket guid was randomly chosen for each request. When I started using consistent real-world market guids, it worked as expected.